# DirectCompute shader (HLSL) has strange array size

Tags: directx, hlsl, directcompute

I'm struggling by the way a compute shader store an array of uint.
I have the following shader code (A simple minimalist example to reproduce the problem):

```
cbuffer TCstParams : register(b0)
{
    int    IntValue1;
    uint   UIntArray[10];    // <== PROBLEM IS HERE
    int    IntValue2;
}

RWTexture2D<float4>                Output         : register(u0);

[numthreads(1, 1, 1)]
void CSMain()
{
    if (IntValue1 == 0)
        Output[uint2(0, 0)] = float4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Once compiled, I examine the ouput of the compiler to know the offet and size of the constant buffer items. The item "uint UIntArray[10];" surprisingly has a size of 148 bytes. This is strange given the fact that uint is 4 bytes. So I expect the array size to be 40 bytes.

Here is the compiler output:

```
Microsoft (R) Direct3D Shader Compiler 6.3.9600.16384
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

//
// Generated by Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 6.3.9600.16384
//
//
// Buffer Definitions: 
//
// cbuffer TCstParams
// {
//
//   int IntValue1;                     // Offset:    0 Size:     4
//   uint UIntArray[10];                // Offset:   16 Size:   148 [unused]    // <== PROBLEM IS HERE
//   int IntValue2;                     // Offset:  164 Size:     4 [unused]
//
// }
//
//
// Resource Bindings:
//
// Name                                 Type  Format         Dim Slot Elements
// ------------------------------ ---------- ------- ----------- ---- --------
// Output                                UAV  float4          2d    0        1
// TCstParams                        cbuffer      NA          NA    0        1
//
//
//
// Input signature:
//
// Name                 Index   Mask Register SysValue  Format   Used
// -------------------- ----- ------ -------- -------- ------- ------
// no Input
//
// Output signature:
//
// Name                 Index   Mask Register SysValue  Format   Used
// -------------------- ----- ------ -------- -------- ------- ------
// no Output
cs_5_0
dcl_globalFlags refactoringAllowed | skipOptimization
dcl_constantbuffer cb0[1], immediateIndexed
dcl_uav_typed_texture2d (float,float,float,float) u0
dcl_temps 2
dcl_thread_group 1, 1, 1

#line 13 "E:\Development\Projects\Test Projects\DirectCompute\TestShader1.hlsl"
if_z cb0[0].x
  mov r0.xyzw, l(0,0,0,0)
  itof r1.xyzw, l(1, 1, 1, 1)
  store_uav_typed u0.xyzw, r0.xyzw, r1.xyzw
endif 
ret 
// Approximately 6 instruction slots used
```

I checked with various array sizes and the result is very strange: the size per element is differents when the number of element change!

What am I doing wrong or what miss I?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-packing-rules):

> Arrays are not packed in HLSL by default. To avoid forcing the shader to take on ALU overhead for offset computations, every element in an array is stored in a four-component vector.

So `uint UIntArray[10];` is actually stored as a `uint4 UIntArray[10];`, except the last three padding uints are not included in the size calculation (even though they still count towards the offset calculation).

If you want a tighter packing, you can declare the array as `uint4 UInt4Array[4];` and then cast it: `static uint UInt1Array[16] = (uint[16])TCstParams.UInt4Array;` (Haven't check if that code is correct, but it should be something similar). The cast itself should not cause any overhead - however, accassing elements in `UInt1Array` will introduce additional instructions to compute the actual offset.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the documentation. To have a tighter packing, I must divide the size by 4 and use uint4. I understand that. But I don't understand at all how to use the cast you show. In the actual code using the array, I have to access each uint individually. Using the cast, can I avoid computing myself the correct uint4 component at some index based of the equivalent uintarray index?

Comment: Yes, the cast just tells the compiler to compute the correct index and component automaticly. It's just a shorthand to make accessing values in tighlty packed arrays more convinient.

Comment: Well, I know what a cast is. What I dont' understand how to apply the line you show which is merely a variable declaration with an initialisation. Currently to access one array element I use this: MyFunct(UInt4Array[Index>>2][Index&3]); Using the cast it becomes MyFunct(((uint[16])UIntArray)[Index]) if I understand well. Not much readable imo.

Comment: The idea is to use the cast in a seperate line and then call `MyFunct(UIntArray[index])`. Whether you are using the cast or not is up to you, the instructions should end up being the same either way, so use whatever suites you better